# Vim map key combination of Control and Dash

Tags: vim, key-binding

Is it possible to bind `<C-->`
(or `<C-dash>` or `<C-minus>`, I actually do not know) in vim to something, like `<C-W><C-Q>`?

What does it mean `<C-->` in the default binding?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could make that binding work in *gvim*, but not in *vim* running in a terminal, because you are unlikely to find a keyboard configuration which sends a different sequence of characters for <kbd>control/Minus</kbd>.  As a rule, the <kbd>control</kbd> modifier affects only a few non-alphabetic characters.

Here is a screenshot from [`vttest`](http://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest.html), which happens to illustrate the usual set of control keys:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the command by typing `control-v`, then the key combo you want.

So for "control" + "minus", enter the following on a new line in your `~/.vimrc`:

`nnoremap *type on your keyboard*<ctrl-v><ctrl-minus>*end type* :MyCommand<cr>`

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: Is ```*type on your keyboard*``` really part of the command?

Comment: No. That's my way of saying "literally enter these keystrokes". My explanation is an attempt to show you a mixture of the actual text that would appear in your `.vimrc`, and what you would type at your keyboard.

Comment: To whoever down-voted: did you try this and it did not work for you? I ask because earlier today I was looking to setup control+minus myself, and this is what I did to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a UK keyboard where underscore is shift-minus, and I found I could map a key to `<C-_>` (i.e. control-underscore) and it works with control-minus (though as @Thomas says above, not in a terminal window because that's predefined to zoom out)

I couldn't find that documented anywhere - it was just a hunch. I'm not sure what would happen on other keyboards.